# Email verification- Blank page when logging in after verified

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently used a tutorial from http://tutsforweb.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/registration-system-with-email.html. I have added a new field in my user table called 'com_code' as stated and defined the default as NULL.

Both confirm.php and registeraction.php work as the passkey variable is inserted into the com_code field in the database when a user registers, and when they click on the verify link in the email they have been sent, the com_code field is then set to NULL.

My problem is when this user logs in, a *blank page appears* ( with the url stuck at loginaction.php where I process the form). Any ideas where I have gone wrong in my loginaction.php code? I am new to PHP so as much explanation as possible would be great!!

**loginaction.php**

```
<?php require 'config/init.php';
 // Get the data collected from the user and database

$email = trim($_POST["email"]);

$password = trim($_POST["password"]);


//Check for errors

if (empty($email) or empty($password)) {

$_SESSION["message"] = "Must enter Email and Password ";

header("Location: login.php");  //Redirection information

exit ;//Ends the script

}

$email = strip_tags($email);

$password = strip_tags($password);

$pwd = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND com_code is NULL";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify($pwd, $row['password'])) {
            $_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"] = $email;
            $_SESSION["unauthenticatedAdmin"] = $_SESSION['usertype'] == '0';

            //We could also use information drawn from the database eg ID

            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

            if ($_SESSION['usertype'] == '1') {
                header("Location: admin.php");
            } else {
                header("Location: profile.php");
            }

        }
        else {
            //Login was unsuccessful

            $_SESSION["message"] = "Could not login as $email";
            header("Location: login.php");   //Go back to the login pages
        }
}//End else
?>
```

Comment: Blank page => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php inside all pages and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php requires connection for it `mysqli_error($mysqli)`  then add an `else{...}` to any `if`'s to see what fires up.

Comment: This would be easier to spot if your indenting was consistent, but there's nothing in the else for your `if ($result->num_rows === 1) {` statement. So if that doesn't return a single row, there's no content to print out.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii-. I have used an else with 'if ($result->num_rows === 1)' and it has returned the else, so this has a problem

Comment: @Jess - why don't you `echo $result->num_rows` and see what's in there?

Comment: Please sanitize your input, its an extra function call.
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);

if your not connected this function returns string empty.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Jess *Sidenote* about the use of `trim()` against a password POST array. Read the following http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79681/ and that could also apply to the use of `strip_tags()` should you be doing when using `password_hash()` somewhere. Plus, you should add `exit;` after every header.

Comment: Hi @andrewsi, I did this and got '0'.

Comment: @Jess also, what is the password column's length/type? if the length is anything less than 60, then that's an issue and MySQL will fail silently because of it.

Comment: @Jess - then your query isn't finding any matching records (so the empty else statement is being run). You need to figure out why that's happening - is the email address right? Is the com_code indeed NULL?

Comment: @andrewsi I have used this exact code before and it usually logs in. The problem must be with com_code. i'm using PHPMyAdmin and when creating the field I clicked the 'null' value and set the value to default. It has varchar (255) also

Comment: @Jess - Doublecheck and make sure that the record you're testing with does indeed have a NULL in the database.

Comment: @andrewsi yep, underneath is has _NULL_

Comment: @Jess - then it's debug time. Take the `com_code` from the WHERE in your code; does it work now? If no, then there's an issue with the email. If yes, then there's an issue with `com_code` - tweak your code to `SELECT com_code` and then `var_dump` the result out to see what the database actually contains

Comment: @andrewsi okay, so I took out com_code.It doesn't work for THIS email address (only one with com_code field filled in) but it works fine for all the rest. In terms of the SELECT, this value appeared on the page 'string(81) "SELECT com_code FROM user WHERE email='j.davidson9599@student.leedsbeckett.ac.uk'" 0'

Comment: @Jess what I don't get is that you have both `$password = trim($_POST["password"]);` and `$pwd = $_POST["password"];`. Any particular reason? Then you're using `strip_tags()` against the password and that will strip out `$` characters if any are present in the password or any other characters that `strip_tags()` may strip out. `$password = "asafsf$aaaaa";

echo $pw = strip_tags($password);` produced `asafsf` and strips everything after the `$` and including it.

Comment: @Jess - it looks like the database thinks the value of `com_code` is 0, rather than null.

Comment: `$_SESSION["unauthenticatedAdmin"] = $_SESSION['usertype'] == '0';` - not sure what you want to do here. One equal then the next being 2.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is used to stop people who are not admins accessing code.

Comment: @andrewsi is there a way I can stop this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the $pwd I am using to hash the user password but didn't realise I did not need both, thanks

Comment: you're welcome. However, I strongly suggest you don't use `strip_tags()` or `trim()` against your password POST arrays or variables, as I already outlined with a link given above and if a user later uses `$` in their password, it will fail when using `strip_tags()` and if a password does contain a space. Both are valid characters for passwords.

Comment: As @Fred-ii- pointed out `$_SESSION["unauthenticatedAdmin"] = $_SESSION['usertype'] == '0';` will throw a notice and neither variable gets set.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've used this code before just without the com_code and it all works perfectly!  would do that now I've added com_code?